# problem importing MRTK AR project to IOS devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, mrtk

I am working on importing my MRTK project to my iPad.
I followed the steps from this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/supported-devices/using-ar-foundation?view=mrtkunity-2021-05

But my background on iPad is still dark like in the unity. So this is my settings:

My camera settings:
[cameraSetting1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TvvB.jpg)

[CameraSetting2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wry6O.jpg)

My package manager:

[Package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1lQ5.jpg)

My build settings:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrypR.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2trMk.jpg)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwe9A.jpg)
I also uncheck the strip engine code. I really don't know which step is wrong, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does it ask for camera access on first run? Please make sure the camera access is granted in your iOS.

Comment: No, it doesn't, I just found the problem that I forgot to update the MRTK UnityAR scripting defines by invoking the menu item: Mixed Reality > Toolkit > Utilities > UnityAR > Update Scripting Defines

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who met the same problem, make sure to check if you forget the step that updates the MRTK UnityAR scripting defines by invoking the menu item: Mixed Reality > Toolkit > Utilities > UnityAR > Update Scripting Defines.